# Xcode, amount of compile sources "doubled" when compiling

Tags: xcode

I've been struggling all day trying to run a project with lots of compile sources (441 exactly), which takes a while to compile. Not sure what I've done on xcode, but suddenly the number of compile sources that appears on building info is twice the real sources amount, taking double time to compile :(

[image]
[image]

Anyone knows what may I be missing?

Comment: And, just to make sure, you didn't make any major changes or add any additional files to you project before this change occurred?

Comment: @CalebB, no I didn't, the weird thing is that the number of source files is just twice.

Comment: Is there a way you can check to see if it's building the project twice for some reason and registering the two passes as different build items?

Comment: I don't know of any :( Any tip for things I could try would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm doing some digging but in the mean time if there is a status viewer you could take a look at the first build item and mark it down somehow and see it the 442nd build item is the same item.

Comment: 1. You can watch details about what's happening under the Report navigator in Xc6 (the chat-bubble-like icon)
2. What scheme are you building when this happens, and have you managed to change the "build active architecture only" flag in Build Settings?

Comment: Thanks both of you, it seems all I did was unplug my iphone from laptop; since no specific device was selected, I'm guessing it was compiling for every iOS version I had, does that make sense? Plugging the iPhone again is compiling just 441 files.

Answer (score 4):

In your target's Build Settings, look for "Build Active Architecture Only". My guess is yours is set to "NO", which means it will build a Universal binary able to run on all of your valid architectures.

When "YES" is selected, it means that it will only build what's necessary to run on a device you have plugged in.

For release builds, you want to make sure this is set to NO so the Universal binary gets created.

Answer (score 0):

• Because you are selecting the target as **generic iOS device**, means it will compile both architectures. just change your target device and run.

• if it is not working you can check @ssantos answer also.